# validating and display error messages for specific form controller in a form array angular

Tags: javascript, validation, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }
  get vehicleGroup(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.myForm.get('vehicleGroup');
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      vehicleGroup: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          vehicle: ['', Validators.required]
        })
      ], [Validators.required]),
    });
  }

  addVehicles(): void{
    const itemToAdd = this.fb.group({
      vehicle: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.vehicleGroup.push(itemToAdd);
  }
  deleteVehicle(i: number){
    this.vehicleGroup.removeAt(i);
  }

  save(): void{
    console.log('save');
  }
}
```

```html
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="myForm">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name">
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="vehicle">Vehicle</label>
      <div formArrayName="vehicleGroup" *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicleGroup.controls; let i=index">
        <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="i">
          <div>
            <input id="{{'vehicle'+i}}" type="text" formControlName="vehicle">
            <button type="button" (click)="deleteVehicle(i)"
              *ngIf="vehicleGroup.length >= 2">remove
            </button>                  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="link-button" [disabled]="!vehicleGroup.valid" (click)="addVehicles()">
          + Add more vehicles
      </button>
      </div>
 </div> 
</form>
```

I have this [(stackBlitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fvtcff) simple form created with angular `formBuilder`

I simple need to how to validate each elements of the dynamic `formArray` and display a unique message for each of them if that particular field is not valid. 
I tried several solutions and also tried `custom validator function` with return an `ValidatorFn`. with that I could simply validate the `formArray`, but It's not good enough for my scenario and still I can not display messages according to the validate functions behavior. How ever to narrow it down, I simply need to know if there is a better way to validate each dynamic elements of this `formArray`. these are the validate rules.

1. each filed value should be unique.
2. need to validate real time
3. after adding few elements, someone edit previously added field, it also should be validate in real time with every other field values(this is where I got struck, I could validate upwards from the editing field, but not the fields below the editing field is validated accordingly)

If some one can show me some way to achieve this in a right way, It would be really great, since I'm struck with this for almost 3 days now, and still can't get an better solution.

Comment: your stackblitz demo is not working properly

Comment: @yougeen I'll update the question with my `component.ts` and `template`

Comment: Can you pls post the error in the console ?

Comment: @RonakKhangaonkar no there's no error there, I just needs a way to validate the dynamically added `formControl`'s to the `formArray`, each in real time and display a message where under the elements which has errors.

Comment: Edited the StckBlitz demo, and it's working now

Comment: You are grouping the form array in wrong way, best way would be making "vehicleGroup" as fb.group instead of fb.array and try declaring array inside the group but not group inside an array

Comment: @shikhar but still I can not validate each form control has unique values inside the form array right. I'm looking for a way to validate the form controls inside the form array here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used unique validator of `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators` in my project. It can be used directly in the component without creating any custom validation function.

You can edit your addVehicles method as follows:

```
addVehicles(): void{
    const itemToAdd = this.fb.group({
      vehicle: ['', RxwebValidators.unique()]
    });
    this.vehicleGroup.push(itemToAdd);
  }
```

and adding

```
ReactiveFormConfig.set({"validationMessage":{"unique":"Enter unique value in the input"}});
```

to ngOnInit.

Here is the [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drlmmr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This is great, I didn't here about the `RxwebValidators` before. Got to dig deep in to that. Thank you so much